# Call service function from DOM - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Is there any way to call the function defined in service from a DOM, I can call components function from DOM but how can we call service function, something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilsService {
    constructor() {}

    getSessionId() {}
}

<button name="getsession" (click)="UtilsService.getSessionId()">Get Session</button>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scope for expressions in view bindings is limited to the the components class instance. 
There is no support to access statics, globals, types (enums), ... directly from the view.

To be able to refer to it in the view, it has to be accessible via the components class instance:

```
constructor(public utilsService:UtilsService) {}
```

```
<button name="getsession" (click)="utilsService.getSessionId()">Get Session</button>
```

Comment: Is it good to call the service directly from HTML? Don't we have to call the service method through the component?

Comment: I don't think you can say this in general. If you conclude to ban that in your projects coding style guide, then of course don't do it, otherwise decide for yourself. I think the most important thing is to stay consistent. Code in HTML files is usually harder to discover, so I'd try to avoid that in general, and if necessary then only call event handlers in the components code file like you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

As usual Gunter answer is perfect, I just wanted say that expose those function on view which are necessary. Don't expose everything from a service on view ([**Law_of_Demeter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

**View**

```
<button name="getsession" (click)="getSessionId()">Get Session</button>
```

**Component Class**

```
export class MyComponent {
    getSessionId: any;
    constructor(private utilsService:UtilsService) {
       this.getSessionId = utilsService.getSessionId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `getSessionId = utilsService.getSessionId;` be inside the constructor? I'd make it a setter instead anyway. I assume you're referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was talking about loose coupling, but never know about that **Law_of_Demeter**, thanks for link & heads up, you're just awesome :)

Comment: I actually meant `getter` instead of `setter` in my previous comment. It depends on the use case though (how often and when the value changes).